# C# - Oracle Transaction Exception - Lot of users at same time - "Execute requires the Command object to have a Transaction..."

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions

I've developed a web application. Some methods use Transactions. Everything works fine,
except when several users start using the webapplication at the same
time. I often get the following message:

> **"Execute requires the Command object to have a Transaction object when the Connection object assigned to the Command is in a pending
>   local transaction. The Transaction property of the Command has not
>   been initialized."**

This is the situation at the moment:

1) There is a webapplication with a lot of different methods that access
an Oracle database. These methods do not interact with each other, each
method performs its own tasks.

2) Some methods use a transaction, some execute only a single SQL
statement and therefore do not use a transaction.

When one user uses the application, everything works fine. There is no
error in code or transactions that do not work.

When other users start using the application at the same time, sometimes
the error mentioned before occurs. This error can occur in methods that
do not even have anything to do with methods that use transactions.

We use Oracle 10g as the database.

Sample of code:

public String NS_INFO_ESTUDO_TECNICO_MOD(StringDictionary strDict)
 {

```
 OpenConn();

 OracleTransaction oTrans = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);


 OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

 command.Transaction = oTrans;

 command.CommandText = "GOMNET_PROJETOS.NS_INFO_ESTUDO_TECNICO_MOD";

 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 try
 {
     OracleParameter param30 = new OracleParameter("nCodigoError",OracleType.Number);
     param30.Size = 1000;
     param30.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

     command.Parameters.Add(param30);

      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (param30.Value.ToString() != "0")
     {
         oTrans.Rollback();
         return ObtemMensagem(param30.Value.ToString());
     }
     else
     {
         oTrans.Commit();
     }
  return "0"; 
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     throw e;
 }
 finally
 {
     command.Dispose();
 }
```

}

This application has too much DB access without close connection. Use command.Dispose() in lot of methods.

Comment: Why you had static connection object to begin with?

Comment: sorry, i need to update my ask. My application does not have static connection anymore. But the problem still with a lot of users at same time.

Comment: Can you post some code? Will help ...

Comment: have you tried to close connection after each transaction? In Finally Block add `connection.Close()`. If you want to reuse connections I would suggest using connection pooling.

Comment: is there also an oracle error number associated with the error message?

Comment: no, it is a C# error with oracle transaction - OracleConnection